# Maxima block and variable

Tags: maxima

I want to display the square of numbers 1 to 5 using block command:

```
expr : 10*i;

myList (expr, iMin, iMax) := block(
  local(expr),
  print(expr),
  print(''expr),
  print( makelist(expr, i, iMin, iMax)),
  print( makelist(''expr, i, iMin, iMax)) 
 )$

ai : i^2$
myList (ai,1,5);
```

Here's what I get with this code:

```
i^2
10*i
[i^2,i^2,i^2,i^2,i^2]
[10,20,30,40,50]
```

Why the "expr" variable (with quote quote) in the myList  is not the variable "ai"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that quote-quote is applied only at the time the expression is input, not when it is evaluated. Try `grind(myList);` to see that quote-quote has interpolated (pasted) the current value of `expr` into the function definition.

The longer answer is that Maxima generally has a one-time evaluation policy (i.e. variables are evaluated just once), but some functions "quote" (do not evaluate) their arguments or evaluate their arguments in a peculiar way, and `makelist` is one of those. That makes it tricky to write a function like `myList` which wants to supply an argument to `makelist`.

My advice is to write `apply(makelist, [...])` (i.e. apply `makelist` to the list of arguments) instead of `makelist(...)`. Writing it with `apply` will ensure that the arguments are evaluated.

```
(%i5) myList(expr, iMin, iMax) := apply (makelist, [expr, i, iMin, iMax]) $
(%i6) expr:i^2 $
(%i7) myList(expr, 1, 5);
(%o7)                          [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```