# wxMaxima - How to hand over variable to makelist inside block?

Tags: list, function, eval, block, maxima

I want to create a function (in wxMaxima) that evaluates an expression and returns x- and y-values.
Inputs are

- expr - the expression
- var - the variable that the expression should be evaluated for
- a - start of the interval
- b - end of the interval
- n - number of steps

Currently it lookes like this:

```
funvalues(expr,var,a,b,n) :=  block(
        [d,t,f],
        d:(b-a)/(n-1),
        t:makelist(i,i,a,b,d),
        f:makelist(expr,var,t),
        [t,f,expr,var,d]
);
```

Using it should look like this:

```
(%i313) funvalues(x^2,x,0,5,6);
(%o313) [[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,4,9,16,25],x^2,x,1]
```

instead this happens:

```
(%i313) funvalues(x^2,x,0,5,6);
(%o313) [[0,1,2,3,4,5],[x^2,x^2,x^2,x^2,x^2,x^2],x^2,x,1]
```

It seems like handing over the variable to the second makelist-command does not work properly. 
I tried tinkering around with some evflags, but I do not know them good enough to say that it can't be solved that way.

Writing everything directly to makelist works:

```
(%i362) kill(x,expr,var,t,f)$
    t: makelist(i,i,0,5,1);
    f: makelist(x^2,x,t);

    (t) [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    (f) [0,1,4,9,16,25]
```

I am sure I could work around this somehow but obviously I lack some understanding of how Maxima works.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it. This way it works:

```
funvalues(expr,var,a,b,n) :=  block(
        [d,t,f],
        d:(b-a)/(n-1),
        t:makelist(i,i,a,b,d),
        f:apply(makelist,[expr,var,t]),
        [t,f,expr,var,d]
);
```

I only found this : 
[stackoverflow.com/questions/42819545/maxima-block-and-variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819545/maxima-block-and-variable) 
after posting the question. And yes, I searched for a good amount of time in advance. (Too long in fact.) 
So ... sorry. And hopefully this will be useful to someone. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use apply on makelist, so the symbol is interpreted.
Here is an example to make it clear:

```
thislist : makelist((x+c)*cos(x),c,-5,5,1),
thislist,
```

and the result is

```
[(x-5)*cos(x),(x-4)*cos(x),(x-3)*cos(x),(x-2)*cos(x),(x-1)*cos(x),x*cos(x),(x+1)*cos(x),(x+2)*cos(x),(x+3)*cos(x),
(x+4)*cos(x),(x+5)*cos(x)]
```

but

```
func := (x+c)*cos(x),
thislist : makelist(func,c,-5,5,1),
thislist,
```

gives

```
[(x+c)*cos(x),(x+c)*cos(x),(x+c)*cos(x),(x+c)*cos(x),(x+c)*cos(x),(x+c)*cos(x),(x+c)*cos(x),(x+c)*cos(x),(x+c)*cos(x),
(x+c)*cos(x),(x+c)*cos(x)]
```

and finally, with

```
func := (x+c)*cos(x),
thislist : apply(makelist, [func, c,-5,5,1]),
thislist,
```

gives

```
[(x-5)*cos(x),(x-4)*cos(x),(x-3)*cos(x),(x-2)*cos(x),(x-1)*cos(x),x*cos(x),(x+1)*cos(x),(x+2)*cos(x),(x+3)*cos(x),
(x+4)*cos(x),(x+5)*cos(x)]
```